# django filter by priority

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a `status` model field which contain list of priorities which are given to the contacted person, from `virgin` to `client`, the `virgin` been the low priority and `client` the high priority, now the question is how can I filter them so I can show all contacts from highest to lowest, so this is the order that I need to show them `client`, `qualified`, `contacted`, `virgin`, this is the model field

```
class LeadContact(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, 
                                  choices=LeadContactConstants.STATUSES,
                                  default=LeadContactConstants.STATUS_PRISTINE)
```

and choices:

```
class LeadContactConstants(object):
    STATUS_PRISTINE = "PRISTINE"
    STATUS_CONTACTED = "CONTACTED"
    STATUS_QUALIFIED = "QUALIFIED"
    STATUS_CLIENT = "CLIENT"

    STATUSES = ((STATUS_PRISTINE, "Virgin"),
                (STATUS_CONTACTED, "Contacted"),
                (STATUS_QUALIFIED, "Qualified"),
                (STATUS_CLIENT, "Client"))
```

Comment: This why I prefer to stock interger for different status in my database. Easier to filter or order. A solution will be to get all your result in 4 different datastructure. And after that combine this 4 different datastructure in the order desire.

Comment: can you show me on some example?

Comment: Can you show me the name of your model. And the values of STATUS_PRISTINE, STATUS_CONTACTED etc.

Comment: you have a model field in my question with `STATUSES` i will link pristine inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
virgin_data = LeadContact.objects.filter(status=LeadContact.STATUS_PRISTINE)
contacted_data = LeadContact.objects.filter(status=LeadContact.STATUS_CONTACTED)
qualified_data = LeadContact.objects.filter(status=LeadContact.STATUS_QUALIFIED)
client_data = LeadContact.objects.filter(status=LeadContact.STATUS_CLIENT)
order_data = list(client_data) + list(qualified_data) + list(contacted_data) + list(virgin_data) # Now order_data contains your data in this specific order. Client - qualified - contacted - virgin
```

If you want only spécific fields about your models, you can used [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) method.